# CakeDC Tags Plugin on Cakephp v2?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Has anyone succeeded to install the CakeDC tags plugin on Cake v2.x?

It seems at though the whole cake command line has changed quite a bit (no more migration and with the directory structure changes, the schema is also broken)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to [this CakeDC](https://github.com/CakeDC/tags) plugin then it is already formatted for cake 2.x. Just create a folder called `Tags` in your plugin directory and then drop the plugin contents in there. Then open the `Config/bootstrap.php` file in your main app and add to the bottom `CakePlugin::load('Tags');`

Comment: "Just create a folder called CakeDc"? CakeDC is the company name, not the plugin name! The plugin is still called "Tags".

Comment: What do you mean, I can name a plugin `virtually` whatever I want.

Comment: Thanks! it seems to not complain anywhere now :)

But I can't seem to make it work, upon updating (after adding the $actsAs) it fails on some odd error: 
[code]Fatal error: Call to undefined function ctype_digit() in /srv/www/htdocs/cake/lib/Cake/Utility/Hash.php on line 624[/code]